# Coverter Int em Vachar - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Fala pessoal boa tarde.

to fazendo uma relação de colunas na minha tabela Arquivos. E eu precisava converter uma coluna "ID_Pasta" que esta do tipo INT em Varchar na hora que eu  Trouxesse os dados apos a query no banco.
Mas nao sei como converter. Alguem poderia me ajudar

meu codigo da query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT id_pasta, nome, id_usuario, de, ate
FROM arquivos 
WHERE ate between '2020-06-30' and '2020-08-15'
ORDER BY ate;
```

Comment: Tentou utilizar a função `cast`?

Comment: Sim, fiz um teste apenas com a coluna ID_PASTA mas so me retorna apenas o numero Inteiro.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que converter utilizando a função `CAST` ou `CONVERT` para o datatype `CHAR` . Não existe conversão para `VARCHAR` .

Por exemplo :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(id_pasta as CHAR(50)), nome, id_usuario, de, ate
FROM arquivos 
WHERE ate between '2020-06-30' and '2020-08-15'
ORDER BY ate;

 SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(id_pasta as CHAR(50)), nome, id_usuario, de, ate
FROM arquivos 
WHERE ate between '2020-06-30' and '2020-08-15'
ORDER BY ate;
```